# TSQL Copy Entry to Same Table as well as Create

Tags: sql, copy

is it possible to copy a single entry to two tables in one query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create an insert trigger on one of the tables where you insert the data into the other. You can do the same for updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OUTPUT INTO clause to copy the inserted data into a second table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblsrc(id int NULL);
CREATE TABLE #tbldest1(id int NULL);
CREATE TABLE #tbldest2(id int NULL);

INSERT INTO #tblsrc VALUES (99);

INSERT INTO #tbldest1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO #tbldest2
SELECT id FROM #tblsrc;

SELECT * FROM #tbldest1;
SELECT * FROM #tbldest2;
```